# EMET disable DEP on IE for specific site

Tags: emet, vmware

I'm a new user of EMET. I wanted to know if there is anyway to avoid DEP on IE for a specific site.

I want to do this because I use VMware remote server and when I start a remote console, EMET starts blocking iexplore (because of DEP attack) and the console doesn't work well. If I close the IE tab, EMET stops throwing errors, but I wish I didn't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. DEP is enforced process-wide, and you can't switch it off for just one site.

There are two ways around this:

- Turn off DEP enforcement in the EMET policy for `iexplore.exe`
- Manually patch the DEP flag into whatever VMware component is being loaded, using a tool such as [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php) (Optional Header -> DllCharacteristics -> Image is NX compatible) so that it is marked as DEP enabled and works alongside EMET.

You should file a bug with VMware about this, as they shouldn't be producing non-NX binaries.

Comment: I'd already turn off DEP for `iexplore.exe`. I will file the bug to VMware and hope the do something about it. Thanks!